# document.width - IE Bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to set the width and height of a mask behind a modal window.

I am using `$(document).width()` and `$(document).height()`.

Works great in FF and Chrome but IE adds about 25px to each and I end up with scroll bars?  What am I supposed to use that is cross browser compatible?

I am using IE8 btw, but I want it to work down to 6 or 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `$(window).width()` & `$(window).height()` ([demo](http://jsbin.com/ugajo4/4)).

Comment: +1 since this is what I ended up doing and some moron -1'ed you. =/

Answer (score 4):

Question: Are you using a doctype on your page? It sounds like the kind of glitch you may get if IE goes into quirks mode, which can be avoided if you use a doctype.

If you haven't got one, all you need is a very simple line at the top of your site:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes I do - I've tried <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> AND <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to fill up the view-port `$(window).width()` and `$(window).height()` is what you want to use.  Works in IE.

Comment: -1. Wow.  Next time leave a comment.  Seeing as I asked the question and this is what fixed my issue, I would say that this is a solid answer.  I just want the next guy who runs into this to be able to fix it.  Come back and leave a message.